# How to execute any code while the button is pressed?

Tags: xml, kotlin, listener, android-button, clicklistener

I have a `button` and `imageView` and I need to execute some code that changes image properties while `button` is pressed. But I do not know how to realize it. I tried to use `onTouchListener` by executing code:

```kotlin
while(event?.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
```

But it causes the app to hang.

Comment: Do you mean code that executes repeatedly while the button is held down? If you want to do something after a user taps a button, you use a click listener. You can't use `while` loops to wait for UI events because it freezes the app by blocking the UI thread--you have to use listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start your task (whatever it is) when you get an `ACTION_DOWN` event (i.e. the user has pressed your `View`) and stop it when you get an `ACTION_UP` event (the user has lifted their finger or whatever) or an `ACTION_CANCEL` (e.g. the user's dragged their finger outside of the `View`).

That'll give you the *while the button is held* behaviour. But that task needs to run *asynchronously* - coroutines, a thread, a delayed `Runnable` posted to the main looper (you can do this through a `View` by calling one of the `post` methods).

You can't just spin in a loop, the system can't do anything else (including displaying UI changes and responding to touches) until your code has finished running. And if you're waiting for an `ACTION_UP` while blocking the thread, you're not going to get one. (A new `MotionEvent` would come through a later function call anyway.)

Here's a simple example using the looper:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    // This is a reusable Runnable that changes a background, then reposts itself
    // to the task queue to run again in the future.
    private val colourCycleTask = object : Runnable {
        private fun rnd() = (0..255).random()
        
        override fun run() {
            binding.someView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(rnd(), rnd(), rnd()))
            binding.someView.postDelayed(this, 250L)
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)
        binding.button.addHoldListener()
    }

    private fun View.addHoldListener() {
        setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
            var handled = true
            when(event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> view.post(colourCycleTask) // run the task
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    view.removeCallbacks(colourCycleTask) // remove the task from the queue
                    view.performClick()
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> view.removeCallbacks(colourCycleTask)
                else -> handled = false
            }
            handled
        }
    }
    
}
```

Posting a `Runnable` to the main `Looper` is basically adding a bit of your code to a task queue - so you're not blocking the thread and preventing anything else from happening, you're saying to the system "hey, do this at this time please" and it'll try its best to hit that time. And because the `Runnable` re-posts itself at the end, you get that looping behaviour while allowing other code to run, because you're not seizing control of execution. You're just deferring a bit of code to run later, then allowing execution to continue.

*Coroutines* are a neater way to do this I think, but I like to use the `Looper` as an example because it's been a part of Android since the old times, and it can be a simple way to get this kind of behaviour when you have main-thread work that needs a delay or to run for a significant amount of time

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do infinite loops in the main thread, it will hang your app. But it's possible to do asynchronous code that won't block the main thread. Kotlin coroutines can help to do this.

If you're using kotlin coroutines in your project, you can launch a new coroutine with an infinite loop on the `ACTION_DOWN` event. And cancel the corresponding job on the `ACTION_UP` event:

```kotlin
var job: Job? = null
button.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        ACTION_DOWN -> {
            job = launch {
                while (true) {
                    // increasing counter as an example:
                    textView.text = "${counter++}"
                    delay(100)
                }
            }
        }
        ACTION_UP -> {
            job?.cancel()
        }
    }
    false
}
```